# C# close all forms

Tags: c#, forms

I have a problem with my program.

I have 3 Forms: First one opens a second form. Second one opens a third form or returns to the first form. The third form can open the first or second forms.

This is how I open a second Form:

```
private void Open_second_form()
    {
        Form2 myForm = new Form2(Type_person);
        this.Hide();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

The rest of the forms I open exactly the same.

Here is a code for how I close forms. Every Form has this method:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Exit or no?",
                           "My First Application",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            this.Close();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
```

When I open the third form I get 3 MessagesBoxes. If I open first form I got only 1 MessageBox.

I want to close all forms while getting only one MessageBox.

I tried a lot of solutions but none worked. 
I tried `Application.exit();`

Please help me :)

Comment: There is only one method for FormClosing ? or other forms have that

Comment: I think your forms navigation is not clear. I understand the following, am I right?
1 -> 2, then 2 -> 3 or 1. And from 3 -> 2 or 1.

Is the 3 to 2 after a 2 to 3? Is the 3 to 1 after a 1 to 3 or it can be after a 2 to 3?

Comment: Other Forms have exactly the same method Form2_FormClosing and Form3_FormClosing

Comment: In Form 1 there is a button which open Form 2
In Form 2 there are 2 buttons first open Form 1, second open Form 3
In Form 3 there are 2 buttons first open Form 2, second open Form 1

Comment: When you say "open" for example the button in form 2, you will then have 2 times the form 1 opened??

Comment: if they are same namespace use a bool flag to check, like `if(Form1.exitconfirmed) Environment.Exit(1);` , and after `this.Close();` add `Form1.exitconfirmed = true;`

Comment: I don't know If I well understand you. If i open FROM 2, FROM 1 will be hide and close and if I want to return to FROM 1 it will be make a method private void Open_first_form()

Comment: You can use the Dialog Results to manage this navigation.I will do an answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your confirmation message is funny and result is unobvious =D

There are 2 solutions possible to your issue.

1) If user chooses to close application - don't display confirmation anymore

```
private static bool _exiting;

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_exiting && MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to exit?",
                       "My First Application",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        _exiting = true;
        // this.Close(); // you don't need that, it's already closing
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

2) use [`CloseReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) to confirm only user actions

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to exit?",
                       "My First Application",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Ok)
            Environment.Exit(1);
        else
            e.Cancel = true; // to don't close form is user change his mind
    }

}
```

Comment: Exiting with 1 error code means your program's task has been not successful but actually in this code, it was successful since the user is the one who closed it himself.. It should be 0. Maybe it doesn't matter for the most of apps but it does matter for the OS and other programs like Terminals, Sandboxes and compilers or even Game-Launchers etc. Imagine a user is opening your app from other process? That process will listen too carefully to the error code your program is returning after it finishes to tell the user if errors were to happen but you lie to it and then the whole task goes wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this snippet always on my menu form. I hope this helps.

```
for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name != "Menu")
    Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Call the Environment.Exit(0); method

```
 private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the form 1, considering the button is called btnForm1To2

```
private void btnForm1To2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form2 myForm = new Form2(Type_person))
    {
        this.Hide();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Inside FORM 2, considering the button to page 1 is btnForm2To1, and the button to page 3 is btnForm2To3

```
private void btnForm2To1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Just close the form 2, as it was called from form 1, this form will be displayed
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

private void btnForm2To3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form3 myForm = new Form3(...))
    {
        this.Hide();
        DialogResult form3result = myForm.ShowDialog();

        // Now handle the results from form 3 to navigate to form 2 or 1
        // In my example, form 3 replies Abort to go back to 1. On cancel (or other dialog results) we will stay on form 2
        if (DialogResult.Abort.Equals(form3result))
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside FORM 3, considering the button to page 1 is btnForm3To1, and the button to page 2 is btnForm3To2

```
private void btnForm3To1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
}

private void btnForm3To2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

And if you want that the user confirms his click with a MessageBox, just place them before the `this.DialogResult` in each button click method

Comment: Thanks but your code make that forms don't hide, they are still on desktop I have to make them hide or close after opening next form

Comment: I've got problem with equals, what i have to add ? Using System.?

Comment: and I think that you didn't correctly understand with what I have problem. You gave me a help with opening a new Forms but i need how to close them, because when i close the last form i'm getting 3 MessagesBox to confirm close.

Comment: Sorry for the equals, needs a Maj (Equals, not equals).
You can hide/show the screens like you did, see my edit.

For the closing problem, when do you have the problem? When you try to click the close button of a form?

Sorry if my code is not perfect right now, I don't have Visual Studio on my current machine

Comment: Sinatr gave you the right way ;)
BTW the way I provided was more Windows Mobile app oriented

Answer (score 1):

**Note** that this way is **faster** than `Environment.Exit(0);`.

### **WPF**

Set your Window `Closing` Event in (**`###Window.xaml`**)

```
Closing="Window_Closing"
```

and then in (**`###WWindow.xaml.cs`**)

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
        if(w != this)
            w.Close();
}
```

### **Windows Form**

- Go to **`Form#.cs [Design]`** >> Form# Properties
- Then click on Events
- And double-click on `FormClosing`

In (**`Form#.cs`**)

If you're closing from your **Startup** form, it's better to use this code.

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     for(int i = 1; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; ++i)
         Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
 }
```

**else** (*Works for any form*)

```
 private void Form7_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; ++i)
         if(Application.OpenForms[i] != this)
                Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to close all forms (particularly dialog windows) except for the main form, I've found this function to be useful.

```
        public static void closeAll()
    {
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
        if (fc.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int i = (fc.Count); i > 1; i--)
            {
                Form selectedForm = Application.OpenForms[i - 1];
                selectedForm.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You got a little belt-and-suspenders going on with the `for` loop condition. It's fine to start with a count that will change if you're already decrementing the counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

That's what I use whenever I need to close an entire application. It closes all forms, so great for closing everything. I don't know if this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked for me:

```
for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name != "FRM01"&&Application.OpenForms[i].Name!= "FRM02")
                Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
        }
```

Those "FRM" things are the names of my forms, what you can do there is to add as many forms as you like to have as "parents". So each time it iterates it will check if the names of those forms are the ones you wish to keep.

I recommend you add that 'for' into your form closing handler if you wish to control an user from closing parent forms and child forms to still be there.

It is always better to use MDI forms ([MDI link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8))